# Rails 3/1.9.2 debugging...with an IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ide, ruby-1.9.2

I was using NetBeans but it seems that support for Ruby is officially dead (with some community element just starting up).  I've seen threads for hacking ruby-debug to support Ruby 1.9 debugging in NB but I just feel like that's not the way to go.  I just installed Aptana3  which will happily hit breakpoints but there's no support for watch expressions which limits visibility.  I can't seem to find a straight answer as to why it's not supported or whether there are any plans to include it.

Is there a clear winner for debugging Rails3/1.9.2 in some sort of text editor?

Comment: you can always output params to the page using the following line     <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %> I have it in the shared footer of my pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RubyMine 3.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) by Jetbrains will let you debug Rails 1.9.2 like NetBeans used to do. While RubyMine is not free, it is affordable and a great Rails development environment.

**Notice**
*I do not work for JetBrains, I'm just a very satisfied customer.*

Comment: Second that. I started coding ruby in RubyMine a short while ago, after using NetBeans and then vim for several years. RubyMine is the best ruby and rails IDE so far.

Comment: And I third that.  Very polished product.

Comment: What about us open source noobs who refuse to pay a cent?

Comment: Netbeans turned over their Ruby capability to the community. I've not used it since the split so I can't talk to the capability provided, but the plugin is still alive and can be found here http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails